# Disabling the bounce in table view makes to tap the cell twice after trying to overscroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xamarin.ios

In the table view, disabling the bounce makes to tap twice to get detect the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` delegate after trying to over scroll the table view. When the bounce is enabled it gives an empty space at the starting and ending of the table view over scrolling and the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` delegate invoked on a single tap on the cell. Is there any way to fix the double tap on the cell to select it after the user tries to over scroll?

**Code**

**ViewController**

```
public partial class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    public MyViewController() : base("MyViewController", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        sampletable.Source = new TableSource();
    }
}
```

**Table Source**

```
public class TableSource :UITableViewSource
{
    string[] data = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    string[] header = new string[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5" };
    public TableSource()
    {
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (MyTableViewCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(MyTableViewCell.Key);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = MyTableViewCell.Create();
        }
        cell.data = data[indexPath.Row];
        return cell;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(header[indexPath.Section] + "->" + data[indexPath.Row]);
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return data.Length;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return header.Length;
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return header[section];
    }

    public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

**Cell**

```
public partial class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("MyTableViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;
    public string data { get; set; }
    static MyTableViewCell()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName("MyTableViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    protected MyTableViewCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public static MyTableViewCell Create()
    {
        return (MyTableViewCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        countLabel.Text = data;
    }
}
```

I unchecked the Bounce, Bounce Vertical and Bounce Horizontal check boxes in the interface builder

**Update: Native iOS Swift Version Code**

[Here is the **Native iOS Swift Version Code**](https://github.com/SiddharthAbhimanyu/TableViewApp)

Comment: @matt I tried to implement the same using swift, I also had the same problem with it. Added the link for the swift code

Comment: If you can still reproduce this problem in Xcode 9 beta, I would suggest filing a bug with Apple.

Comment: Hi everyone,

I encountered the same problem today. Did you find a solution ?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution,

[image: ScrollView config in interface builder]

Now i can check with one tap instead of two in my tableview.

Hope this can help.